# NotSerializableException on anonymous class using Comparator

Tags: java, serialization, anonymous-class, treeset

I'm getting **NotSerializableException** and the reason is an anonymous inner class how can I make this customized comparator for a TreeSet implements Serializable interface too .

```
badPatients = new TreeSet<Patient>(new Comparator <Patient>() {
        public int compare(Patient p1,Patient p2) {
            if(p1.getStatus() > p2.getStatus())
                return -1;
            if(p1.getStatus() == p2.getStatus())
                return 0;
            return 1;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom interface that extends `Comparator<T>` and also extends `Serializable`:

**SerializableComparator.java**

```java
public interface SerializableComparator<T> extends Comparator<T>, Serializable {
    //Nothing here
}
```

In your code, change the argument from `Comparator<Parent>` to `SerializableComparator<Parent>`.

```java
badPatients = new TreeSet<Patient>(new SerializableComparator<Patient>() {
        public int compare(Patient p1,Patient p2) {
            if(p1.getStatus() > p2.getStatus())
                return -1;
            if(p1.getStatus() == p2.getStatus())
                return 0;
            return 1;
        }
    });
```